Merge [tag:vaccine] and [tag:vaccination]
The tags vaccine and vaccination seem synonymous. Let's merge them?

Vaccine into vaccination

Vaccine is the drug, vaccination is the process of receiving the drug (the vaccine). They are not synonymous. At least in medical law they are not. Maybe laymen treat them synonymously. Could you elaborate why we should alias either tag to the other?

@KaiBurghardt agreed but the two tags seem to be used interchangeably in practice.

@KaiBurghardt There's vaccination the process, and vaccination the field: imo, vaccination the field would be an adequate supertag for vaccine the object and vaccination the process.

@wizzwizz4 I cannot confirm that vaccination refers to a scientific discipline, too. Collins, MW, OALD, Wiktionary

@KaiBurghardt The Wikipedia page on vaccination describes vaccines, the vaccine production process… basically everything except the administration of a vaccine, which gets three sentences and a "see also". The Wikipedia page on vaccines has an entire section devoted to the administration of vaccines (i.e., vaccination). Vaccination isn't usually considered a field of study in academia, since different questions about it are best suited to different disciplines.

Tags are supposed to be used to categorize questions into useful categories for the community. They inform the community what a question is about so that readers and potential answerers can find questions that interest them.
To that end, we need to consider the overall scope of this site, which is law. Not every concept needs its own tag, but only those concepts that result in a meaningful distinction within the scope of the site.
On a site about medical sciences, a distinction between vaccine and vaccination could make sense, with the first tag covering the development, manufacture, distribution, ingredients, etc. of vaccines and the latter covering the process of administering vaccines to patients. The people developing, manufacturing and distributing vaccines are typically not the ones administering them to patients, so a distinction really does make sense.
On the other hand, vaccination law is a pretty niche area of law, and so I expect that someone interested in learning about it or contributing answers in it is going to be interested at least somewhat in questions both about the legal effects of manufacturing vaccines in certain ways as well as the legal effects of jabbing them into people's arms under various scenarios. Thus, I think a merger makes sense.
Keep in mind that we don't need a tag for every possible concept. We have the tag motor-vehicle which neatly covers the various area of motor vehicle law. While someone could ask a question about the minimum brightness for headlights to make a car road legal in X jurisdiction, we wouldn't need to add a headlights tag, the motor vehicle tag will do.
